# How does Android Things handle long running background tasks?

Tags: android-things

How are long running background tasks handled in Android Things? Can developers rely on unbound Services being kept alive by the system?

Comment: Services should behave the same way they normally do. If you are experiencing something that you feel is unusual compared to standard Android behavior, please describe it as in as much detail as necessary so that someone can investigate, or file an issue on the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) using either the **Android Things bug** or **Android Things feature request** template.

Comment: So there is no such thing as doze mode in Android Things?

Comment: It seems you can also call [startForeground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) from your service: interesting since that obviously requires a notification, which presumably is simply discarded.

Comment: @jbxbergdev not in PR1 anyway. See https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm asking because in standard Android development, it's considered bad practice to rely on background tasks running indeterminately. Many IoT applications will rely on some sort of ongoing task, though. So developers will need a way to ensure those tasks can run uninterruptedly. Is this already on the roadmap? Or is @JatraTim s suggestion the way to go here? Otherwise, I'll submit a feature request.

Comment: Some clarification in this G+ thread: https://plus.google.com/104601454524498956653/posts/JyPBERee8tR - As of now, the current dp1 doesn't kill services/apps.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are the only application running in Android Things you will not be interrupted like usual on an Android mobile device. You can also just use Services like normal if that is what you desire.

Further you can create a background threaded task, this will not be killed or anything and can continue to run in the background for as long as your Activity is around (which with Android Things, will be the whole lifespan of the device being turned on).

Comment: Can we expect to be the only app? Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I spoke to the guys that wrote it :-) but also https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html "Android Things expects **one application** to expose a "home activity" in its manifest as the main entry point for the system to **automatically launch on boot.** "

Comment: @jbxbergdev and to answer your Doze question: No, no doze mode From the release notes "System power management is currently disabled. Devices will not suspend and wake locks are not necessary" https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html